# renaming files in folder using batch command sequentially names present in text file

Tags: batch, batch-file, batch-rename

i want to sequentially or wildcard rename files that are present in a folder with the names present in a text file using batch program.
say there are 10 .csv files in folder and we have one rename.txt files which contains all the names sequentially ffrom that we have to rename the files present in the folder.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a batch file?  What about Powershell or VBS?

To get you started (there is almost 0 error checking), what about this VBS:
http://pastebin.com/sfCS1swK

The top of the script has the variables you will want to change, note comments:
   RENAME_FILE = "rename.txt"
   bRename        = false
   objStartFolder = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test"

Maybe run it from an admin command prompt as:
cscript rename.vbs > out.txt

Examine the out.txt file to see if it does what you expect before changing bRename = true and re-running it.

Hope it helps.